# Haskell tail function for empty lists

Tags: list, haskell, tail

I have a problem with a function that should only return the tail of a list. The functions is myTail and should give a useable result, even if the input is an empty list.

I want to understand all 3 ways: pattern matching, guarded equation and conditional expressions

this works:

```
> myTail_pat :: [a] -> [a]

> myTail_pat (x:xs) = xs
> myTail_pat [] = []
```

But this:

```
> myTail_guard (x:xs)   | null xs = []
>               | otherwise = xs
```

gives me the error: Program error: pattern match failure: myTail_guard []
How can i declare the function without patterns?

Thank you.

Comment: Might help you: http://cs.anu.edu.au/Student/comp1100/haskell/tourofsyntax.html#Guards

Comment: you can just do `myTail = drop 1`

Comment: The pattern matching version is more haskell-like anyways.

Comment: I know but it was an exercise ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The pattern `x:xs` does not match the empty list. You'd need to do:

```
myTail_guard xs
  | null xs   = []
  | otherwise = tail xs
```

Comment: If you want to avoid `tail xs` I think you could replace it with `xss where (_, xss) = xs`

Comment: @Artelius: that should be `xss where (_:xss) = xs`.

Comment: or lazy patterns

Comment: What reason would someone what to use `xss where (_:xss) = xs` over `tail xs` for this purpose?

Answer (score 13):

drop 1 is safe

```
drop 1 []
-- result: []
```

Comment: Is there any negative effects to using this approach vs the normal tail function or pattern match?

Comment: @Lightbulb1 please define what is a "negative effect", is that a side effect or what. The only difference between "tail" and "drop 1" is that tail throws an error on an empty list.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was thinking in terms of performance.

Comment: Although I believe it's implemented using a linked list so the performance is the same, you must not have the implementation performance under consideration when writing a program in Haskell. In a more philosophic way, in an imperative language you tell the compiler "how to do it" and in a functional one you tell "what you want to get done".  If performance is your priority, then rather take ASM or C golang or something similar.